# Creating highstock zoom-in/out button

Tags: highcharts

I have the following problem - I'm trying to create highstock graphic with zoom-in/zoom-out buttons, but something is wrong with the zooming. When i press the button most of the times the chart zooms to the correct time interval, however, after I press the button a couple more times, the chart starts to behave weird - the animations aren't correct or it doesn't zoom or it zooms to the wrong interval.

This is the zooming function:

```
var xAxis = graphic.xAxis[0];
var minimum = xAxis.dataMin;
var maximum = xAxis.dataMax;

var newMin = 0;
var newMax = 0;

//when zooming out

newMin = xAxis.min - 360000;
newMax = xAxis.max + 360000;

//when zooming in

//newMin = xAxis.min - 360000;
//newMax = xAxis.max + 360000;

if (newMin < minimum)
    newMin = minimum;

if (newMax > maximum)
    newMax = maximum;

if (newMin > newMax) {
    alert("min bigger than max");
}

console.log("newMin: " + newMin + "    newMax: " + newMax);

xAxis.setExtremes(newMin, newMax);
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E5kth/3/

- jquery - 1.6.4
- jquery mousewheel - 3.1.6
- highstock - 1.3.7

Thanks in advance ;]

**EDIT:**
Here is a NEW video with better explanations of the problem: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5x1k5b0lbtqw81u/highstock_ordinal-false_bug_converted.avi
for better quality - download the video, dropbox streaming is with low quality.

Comment: Try to disable animations, otherwise running animation wasn't finished, and you will set new, wrong, extremes: http://jsfiddle.net/E5kth/4/ (first button)

Comment: Ok, I tried it with animations disabled, but i don't see any change. Also in the fiddle you provided it's still buggy.

Comment: No it's not, it works exactly as expected (for me at least). I advice you to try chart with disabled ordinal axis: http://jsfiddle.net/E5kth/5/ - you have huge gaps, so for a while you are trying to zoom, but there is a gap.

Comment: With your last fiddle (5) this is how you reproduce the bug:
- open the fiddle
- zoom in to the first visible bar (by selecting it with the mouse)
- click the zoom in button 2 or 3 times until the graphic gets wider than the view port and no gaps are visible. It doesn't matter if you zoom in until you see the "min/max" alert or not.
- click the zoom out button 2 or 3 times and it's bugged - only the dates are moving and the graphic stands still.

Comment: You are right, that we have huge gaps, which is exactly the reason why we need to use ordinal:true. Setting the ordinal to false renders the graphic useless.

Comment: Which browser? After "min bigger than max" I see only straight line and nothing happens (only alert over and over again).

Comment: The browser is Chrome.
You are right, but after the alert if you click the zoom out button it doesn't show the alert anymore (which is OK) and then no matter how many times you click the zoom out button - the line stays straight, which is not correct behavior. The graphic should go back to earlier states (with lesser zoom level). I hope you understand my problem now ;]

Comment: Yes, I understand, unfortunately I see alert everytime.. I click always left button, it's zooming one, right? For me it looks like you have something wrong in your code, sorry.

Comment: The left button is the zoom in button, right next to it (right button) is the zoom out button, you should click it, like i explained above. I may have errors in my zooming function, but could you please point them out, because after reading your documentation, this is what I've come up with. Please help me use the proper functions to build my zoom functionality.

Comment: Just don't zoom when you have  min > max. I didin't wrote the docs, but for me is pretty ovbious. See fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/E5kth/6/

Comment: I made two videos showing the problems. You can see how after a couple of clicks on the zoom out or zoom in buttons the chart is bugged - it either "zooms" only the timeline but not the chart itself or it does nothing. Here are the links to the videos: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nx46q5qeb6y4p0h/Charts_problem_video1.avi
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5aixa47bgdengxm/Charts_problem_video2.avi
They are better viewed when downloaded.

Comment: Let's talk about second video - this how ordinal axis works. Doesn't matter what extremes are set, always will display points with fixed space between them. For example range is 11-20 of May, but data is only 15-16 of May, so when you zoom by one day you need to click 5 times, before you will see noticable zoom-in for a chart. You have parts of data for 20 minutes, but you are zooming in/out by 1 hour.

Comment: I know how ordinal works, you explained it earlier, and I'm thankful for this. But in the video the date range is from 9th Dec to 11th Dec, which is not that big of a time period and I'm zooming by 1 hour, so after a couple of clicks it should make a difference, but it doesn't. And how about the first video, it is with ordinal=false and it is buggy.

Comment: I'm not a 100% convinced it's solved, but I removed animation on the zoomOut setExtremes, and it seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/E5kth/9/. Also using the latest code from GitHub may help, where a similar bug was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I prepared simple example how it should be done, http://jsfiddle.net/3vB5B/. It get range from  chart and then reduce range on 24 hours.

```
$('#btn').click(function(){

            var min = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min,
                max = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;

            chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes((min + 12 * 3600 * 1000),(max - 12 * 3600 * 1000)); //12 hrs on min and 12hrs on max, summarised it is one day.

});
```

Comment: I updated my zooming function to use your code, but it's still not working correctly, probably because of the intervals in the graphic - http://jsfiddle.net/E5kth/7/ . Your data is without intervals, do you have any idea if the intervals need some specific code?