# Hightcharts: Smooth zoom in/out distance

Tags: highcharts

How to smoothly zoom in and out of the chart using buttons?
Below I gave the code approximation of the graph.
(If this is important: I have Data every second.)

```js
var min = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min,
max = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes((min + 12 * 2000),(max - 12 * 2000));
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current implementation? I see that you have based on the demo from this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21024723/creating-highstock-zoom-in-out-button which adds/deletes the 12 hours. If you want to zoom more or less just change this miliseconds values.

Comment: I need a smooth approach, not a sharp one.

Comment: Before I start digging deeper with this requirement I need more information. Do you use Highcharts or Highstock? And what type of the series needs to be animate?

Comment: Highstock. 
series[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoom smoothness depends on the amount of rendered points on the chart. I have noticed that if dataGrouping is disabled and points amount is less than 250 animation works fine.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hj5Lyda7/

```
var chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    animation: true
  },

  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: data,
    dataGrouping: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }]
});

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function() {


  var min = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().min,
    max = chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max;

  chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes((min + 24 * 3600 * 1000), (max - 24 * 3600 * 1000), true, {
    duration: 2000
  }); //12 hrs on min and 12hrs on max, summarised it is one day.
})
```

I am afraid that for more points it is impossible to keep this smoothness and displayed range must be changed by using the rangeSelector feature.